# Демоны на PHP. WebSocket

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

Насколько PHP плох в этом и почему? Читал на разных форумах что PHP плохо справляется с WebSocket, мол часто падает сервер, большая нагрузка, плохая оптимизация, php не подходит для этого используйте node.js, а вот почему никто не пишит, я вот хочу узнать почему и вообще правда ли это, подскажите.

Например, стоит задача написать чат с посещаемостью 100 чел. на websocket, неужели php справится с эти хуже чем node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Со 100 подключениями справится что угодно. Смотри пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/351012/

Идеологический недостаток в php для этого есть, и он раскрыт в статье https://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/ . "PHP создан что бы умирать" и нет таких продвинутых сборщиков мусоров как в java, параллельное программирование доступно только с "костылями" типа ReatPHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP не предназначен для того, чтобы держать состояние. Если его заставить это делать, то он будет течь по памяти.

Лучшее решение это реализовать WebSocket - сервер на node.js, но в случае 100 пользователей проще будет использовать стороннее решение наподобие https://cloudws.io

Но ещё нужно учитывать насколько там конфиденциальная информация передаётся, потому что хоть они и пишут на сайте, что не хранят сообщения, но кто знает